# How to recover $e$ from $f_A(e) = Ae \mod q$ when knowing trapdoor

Tags: lattice-crypto, trapdoor

I have a silly question, but I don't know a solution, so I need to question.

Assume, with a algorithm $TrapGen(1^\lambda)$, it generates $A\in\mathbb{Z}_q^{n\times m}$ with a basis $B \in\mathbb{Z}_q^{m\times m}$ for $\Lambda^\perp(A)$.

With ISIS problem (inhomogoneous small integer solution), if $SIS_{q,m,2r\sqrt{m}}$, define a function $f_A(e) = Ae \mod q$ where $\Vert e \Vert \leq r\sqrt{m}$, how to recover $e$ when we know $A$ and $B$, and is this solution unique?

$TrapGen$ is defined in  [Generating Shorter Bases for Hard Random Lattices](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~cpeikert/pubs/shorter.pdf)

Comment: For typical parameters $n$, $q$, $m$, solutions are not unique. For an algorithm to sample a random (Gaussian-distributed) solution, see Gentry-Peikert-Vaikuntanathan STOC'08, Trapdoors for hard lattices and new cryptographic constructions.

Comment: Thank @ChrisPeikert, I am going to use $f_A(e)$ like a encryption function. I want to hide e under $f_A(.)$ and $u = f_A(e) \mod q$ is a cipher-text. When I want to invert $e$, I will use $B$ and $A$ to recover $e$. Is it possible?

Comment: The link to the paper is dead